# printfn in a nested function call is not printing anything on console

Tags: f#, printf

I've below mentioned code written in F# language:

```
let f () = 
    printfn "This function will print f"
    0

let xs (x) = 
    printfn "This function will print xs"
    f
    ()


[<EntryPoint>]
let main ( argv : string[]) =
    xs 4 |> ignore
    0
```

When I run this program I get only one print statement (present in `sx` function) on console:

> This function will print xs

The statement `This function will print f` present inside `f` function is not getting printed. Interestingly enough, when I pressed <kbd>F11</kbd> to step into function `f` while debugging the control isn't going there at all even though there is a break point inside function `f`.

More intesrestingly, if I introduce a parameter in function `f` then it all starts working. So if I change the function `f` to:

```
let f (x) = 
    printfn "This function will print f"
    0

let xs (x) = 
    printfn "This function will print xs"
    f 2
    ()


[<EntryPoint>]
let main ( argv : string[]) =
    xs 4 |> ignore
    0
```

Then this print statement starts to work:

> This function will print f
>
> This function will print xs

Can someone explain this strange behavior? I'm sure I'm missing something very basic related to F# world or its functional aspect may be. I've a C# background.

Comment: There is no magic going on. In your first example you define a function f, which has a unit paramater (), you should call it like f(). In your second example you call it with its parameter correctly. The reason is that you have automatic currying in f#, basically f is just a function waiting for its input, you can supply it now or later.

Comment: f is a function if you want to call it you have to write `f()` instead of `f`

Comment: @FoggyFinder ohh! I thought if the call `f 2` works then for parameterless function I should simply remove the parameter `2` and things should work. Strangely enough, why compiler didn't complain during compilation? Even with the statement `f` it runs the program without any error.

Comment: you also don't need to add explicit return values (like 0 or ()), as F# functions automatically return the last evaluated expression, since a print statement is  a side effect it will be unit `()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not calling `f`, you are just placing a function there without giving it the parameters it needs.

That's why it works when you give it a parameter. You also have to do the same with the empty braces:

```
let xs (x) = 
    printfn "This function will print xs"
    f ()
    ()
```

In case you wanted the final `()` to act as the parameters to `f`, you have to add some more indentation:

```
let xs (x) = 
    printfn "This function will print xs"
    f
     ()
```